# Modifying the Cisco SBC Python Code to make a blinking light

Tags: python, cisco

Here is the original python code I'm trying to modify:

```py
from gpio import *
from time import *
count=0
def main():
    pinMode(1, OUT)
    print("Blinking")
    while True:
        digitalWrite(1, HIGH);
        delay(5000)
        digitalWrite(1, LOW);
        delay(2000)
        count+=1
        for count in 7:
        print("On")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

What I'm trying to accomplish is:

**1. When the toggle switch is on:**

> Add a code so the light will blink on for 5 Secs. and then blink off for 2 Secs.

**2. After the switch has been thrown:**

> Print a status message of "On" 7 times.

Here is what I've tried so far:

```py
from gpio import *
from time import *
count=0
def main():
    pinMode(1, OUT)
    print("Blinking")
    while True:
        digitalWrite(1, HIGH);
        delay(5000)
        digitalWrite(1, LOW);
        delay(2000)
        count+=1
        for count in 7:
        print("On")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Please also help me explain each section or line (if possible) of the program with a comment, so I can follow along the code knowing what each line is doing.

Thank you.

Comment: Could you add more details to the question like which libraries you're using and any attempts you've made so far?

Comment: There is no difference between the original python code and what you've said tried so far. Did you paste the same code twice by accident?